# Autofac - IRegistrationSource not applied

Tags: c#, autofac, asp.net-core-3.1

As I need to control the instance injected I have tried to follow this article: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html

Here is my implementation of it:

```
public class ModuleAutofacRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents => false;

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<ServiceRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        var swt = service as IServiceWithType;
        if (swt == null || !typeof(Foundation.Core.Modules.Framework.IModule).IsAssignableFrom(swt.ServiceType))
        {
            // It's not a request for the base handler type, so skip it.
            return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();
        }

        var registration = new ComponentRegistration(
                                    Guid.NewGuid(),
#pragma warning disable CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
                                    new DelegateActivator(swt.ServiceType, (c, p) =>
#pragma warning restore CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
                                    {
#pragma warning disable CS8603 // Possible null reference return.
                                        return ModuleRegistry.Instance.GetModule(swt.ServiceType);
#pragma warning restore CS8603 // Possible null reference return.
                                    }),
                                    new CurrentScopeLifetime(),
                                    InstanceSharing.Shared,
                                    InstanceOwnership.OwnedByLifetimeScope,
                                    new[] { service },
                                    new Dictionary<string, object>());

        return new IComponentRegistration[] { registration };
    }
}
```

So in place of the factory in the example I just return
`ModuleRegistry.Instance.GetModule(swt.ServiceType);`

My registration is done like this:

```
builder.RegisterSource(new ModuleAutofacRegistrationSource());
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dlwAssemblies)
                .Where(x => x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract && typeof(IModule).IsAssignableFrom(x))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .SingleInstance();
```

When I debug, I see that my RegistrationSource is called until my second return but he never call my DelegateActivator and of course the GetModule method.
I have the feeling that autofac is able to resolve it in another way, so he don't need to call my method. In my consumer class I have an "empty" instance of my IModule I mean a class where I didn't have the values injected by my GetModule method.

Regards,

EDIT:

Here is the result of the tracer

```
Resolve Operation Starting
{
  Resolve Request Starting
  {
    Service: Dlw.Kentico.Foundation.Core.Modules.Feature.DynamicResponsiveImage.Services.IResponsiveImageService
    Component: Dlw.Kentico.Foundation.Core.Modules.Feature.DynamicResponsiveImage.Services.ResponsiveImageService

    Pipeline:
    -> CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware
      -> ScopeSelectionMiddleware
        -> SharingMiddleware
          -> RegistrationPipelineInvokeMiddleware
            -> ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware
              -> DisposalTrackingMiddleware
                -> ResponsiveImageService (ReflectionActivator)
                  Resolve Request Starting
                  {
                    Service: Dlw.Kentico.Foundation.Core.Modules.Feature.FocusImageEditor.Repositories.IFocusImageEditorRepository
                    Component: Dlw.Kentico.Foundation.Core.Modules.Feature.FocusImageEditor.Repositories.FocusImageEditorRepository

                    Pipeline:
                    -> CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware
                      -> ScopeSelectionMiddleware
                        -> SharingMiddleware
                          -> RegistrationPipelineInvokeMiddleware
                            -> ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware
                              -> DisposalTrackingMiddleware
                                -> FocusImageEditorRepository (ReflectionActivator)
                                <- FocusImageEditorRepository (ReflectionActivator)
                              <- DisposalTrackingMiddleware
                            <- ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware
                          <- RegistrationPipelineInvokeMiddleware
                        <- SharingMiddleware
                      <- ScopeSelectionMiddleware
                    <- CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware
                  }
                  Resolve Request Succeeded; result instance was Dlw.Kentico.Foundation.Core.Modules.Feature.FocusImageEditor.Repositories.FocusImageEditorRepository
                  Resolve Request Starting
                  {
                    Service: CMS.DocumentEngine.IAttachmentInfoProvider
                    Component: λ:CMS.DocumentEngine.IAttachmentInfoProvider

                    Pipeline:
                    -> CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware
                      -> ScopeSelectionMiddleware
                        -> SharingMiddleware
                        <- SharingMiddleware
                      <- ScopeSelectionMiddleware
                    <- CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware
                  }
                  Resolve Request Succeeded; result instance was CMS.DocumentEngine.AttachmentInfoProvider
                  Resolve Request Starting
                  {
                    Service: Dlw.Kentico.Foundation.Core.Logging.IDlwLogger
                    Component: Dlw.Kentico.Frontend.Modules.Foundations.Logging.DlwLogger

                    Pipeline:
                    -> CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware
                      -> ScopeSelectionMiddleware
                        -> SharingMiddleware
                        <- SharingMiddleware
                      <- ScopeSelectionMiddleware
                    <- CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware
                  }
                  Resolve Request Succeeded; result instance was Dlw.Kentico.Frontend.Modules.Foundations.Logging.DlwLogger
                  Resolve Request Starting
                  {
                    Service: Dlw.Kentico.Foundation.Core.Modules.Feature.ResponsiveImage.IResponsiveImageModule
                    Component: Dlw.Kentico.Frontend.Modules.Features.ResponsiveImage.ResponsiveImageModule

                    Pipeline:
                    -> CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware
                      -> ScopeSelectionMiddleware
                        -> SharingMiddleware
                          -> RegistrationPipelineInvokeMiddleware
                            -> ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware
                              -> DisposalTrackingMiddleware
                                -> ResponsiveImageModule (ReflectionActivator)
                                <- ResponsiveImageModule (ReflectionActivator)
                              <- DisposalTrackingMiddleware
                            <- ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware
                          <- RegistrationPipelineInvokeMiddleware
                        <- SharingMiddleware
                      <- ScopeSelectionMiddleware
                    <- CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware
                  }
                  Resolve Request Succeeded; result instance was Dlw.Kentico.Frontend.Modules.Features.ResponsiveImage.ResponsiveImageModule
                <- ResponsiveImageService (ReflectionActivator)
              <- DisposalTrackingMiddleware
            <- ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware
          <- RegistrationPipelineInvokeMiddleware
        <- SharingMiddleware
      <- ScopeSelectionMiddleware
    <- CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware
  }
  Resolve Request Succeeded; result instance was Dlw.Kentico.Foundation.Core.Modules.Feature.DynamicResponsiveImage.Services.ResponsiveImageService
}
Operation Succeeded; result instance was Dlw.Kentico.Foundation.Core.Modules.Feature.DynamicResponsiveImage.Services.ResponsiveImageService
```

EDIT 2:
More info about what I need to achieve:

1. My class `IResponsiveImageModule` inherit from `IFeatureModule` who inherit from `IModule`
2. During the `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` I create an instance of those Modules (so an instance of the `ResponsiveImageModule`) and I set some properties of this modules based on settings.
3. When inject `IResponsiveImageModule` into my class `ResponsiveImageService` I would like to receive the instance of the object that I have intitialize in the step 2

Answer (score 1):

You're registering a source but also registering assembly types. Sources are queried last - explicit registrations always take precedence. If you're resolving any of the assembly types you're registering, that's why it's not calling that activator.

Situations like this can sometimes be easier to figure out [if you try the diagnostics support](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/debugging.html#diagnostics).

If you're sure that's *not* what's happening, maybe dive deeper in the question to explain what *is* and *is not* being registered via the assembly types call and what you think the source should be handling. There's not enough info here to be able to follow the whole thing.

---

Update based on the change in the question:

**Even with the tracer output, there is not enough here to solve this.** I would recommend making [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the setup with as *absolutely few moving pieces as possible* to narrow down the problem.

There's a lot of important stuff omitted in the current question, ostensibly due to complexity, that is actually required to understand the whole setup and help. For example:

- You're registering `dlwAssemblies` but we don't know what those assemblies are or what types are in them.
- You're expecting *something* (we don't know what) to resolve some sort of "module" (we don't know what) and that module is... expected to come from the source? Or not? That's not totally clear.

This is sort of like a 400 piece puzzle where only 200 pieces are put together and you're asking if I think this section over here is right... but we don't get to see the original picture or the rest of the puzzle pieces.

**In creating your minimal example, it can help you debug your own problem.** That's actually a huge benefit to the effort of making that minimal repro - by removing the extra complexity, it's not only easier for the folks answering the question to see what's going on, it also makes things come clear for you, the person asking the question.

In making that repro, I'd recommend simplifying down to things like:

- Don't include assembly registration. Just register *one type* that you expect to be registered via `RegisterAssemblyTypes`. (If things start working, that points out you should probably check into what's being registered there.)
- Don't call things `module` - it'll be confusing with Autofac modules, at least for folks trying to answer.
- Remove the `#pragma` comments if you post code, it's harder to read with the extra non-essentials.
- Don't have a *bunch* of things you expect to come from your registration source, just have *one*. This way you know it's either going through your registration source or there's *something else* going on.
- Write it like a unit test. One method where you can control everything - setup of the container, resolution of the type. Don't run it through an application request or anything else. If it starts working, you know some of the extra stuff is causing the problem; if it doesn't work, you have far less to focus on fixing.

I'd also strongly recommend reading through the tracer results. That's not just for us, that's for you. If it doesn't make sense, start doing some searches, diving deeper into it. You're creating a registration source, one of the more complex things you can do with Autofac. If you can't read the tracer results, it may indicate you need to step back and understand how more Autofac internals work, which may also mean looking at the code in Github. Yes, that's really deep. If you want to do the hard stuff, you sometimes have to dive in.

Reading the tracer output myself, I see:

- You're resolving an `IResponsiveImageService` which is implemented by `ResponsiveImageService`. This is getting resolved via *reflection* - `ResponsiveImageService (ReflectionActivator)`.
- The `ResponsiveImageService` has **four dependencies** (this is one of the things that would be easier to follow if you were doing a minimal repro).

  - `IFocusImageEditorRepository` (implemented by `FocusImageEditorRepository`) gets resolved by *reflection* - `FocusImageEditorRepository (ReflectionActivator)`
  - `IAttachmentInfoProvider` (implemented by a lambda that returns an object - hence `λ:CMS.DocumentEngine.IAttachmentInfoProvider`) appears to have been already resolved and is being shared, like it's a singleton or "instance per lifetime scope" sort of thing. We see that because it resolves from the `SharingMiddleware`.
  - `IDlwLogger` (implemented by `DlwLogger`) is also either a singleton or somehow shared, also comes from `SharingMiddleware`.
  - `IResponsiveImageModule` (implemented by `ResponsiveImageModule`)  is activated via *reflection* - `ResponsiveImageModule (ReflectionActivator)`

So, given all that, it seems like the `ResponsiveImageModule` is being found via that `RegisterAssemblyTypes` call.

Which makes sense, because your registration...

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dlwAssemblies)
  .Where(x => x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract && typeof(IModule).IsAssignableFrom(x))
  .AsImplementedInterfaces()
  .SingleInstance();
```

...is basically doing exactly that - it's registering, for reflection, any object that can be cast down to `IModule`. And, like I said before, **registration sources are queried last** so if you want the module to come from your registration source then you probably need a `!` in there somewhere so it *doesn't* register your modules. (Though, honestly, it's still kind of unclear what you're really trying to accomplish here and what is or isn't working as expected.)

I hope this helps to unblock you. If anything, maybe it has given you some ideas of places to look. I, unfortunately, have a limited amount of time I can allocate to questions and support and I need to spread it around, so I will *not be coming back for a third iteration* even if you do end up figuring out a minimal repro. The tips and notes here will have to be enough, at least from me, and I'm sorry that's the case. Good luck getting this to work; I think you're really close.

Comment: Hello,
I have updated my question with the tracer result and some details about what I try to achieve here.
Thank you for your help on it.

Comment: @Kapoue I've updated my answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't have a whole answer but maybe it will help. I won't be able to come back for a third round of iteration, so I hope this at least unblocks you or gets you enough to go on to start debugging.